# Is this the right way to escape multiple fields?

Tags: php, security, mysql-real-escape-string

I had just hired someone to do a secure form and pasted below is just a snippet of a large code:

```
        $_POST = escape_all($_POST);

        $some1 = $_POST['some1'];
        $some2 = $_POST['some2'];
        $some3 = $_POST['some3'];
        $some4 = $_POST['some4'];
        $some5 = $_POST['some5'];
        $some6 = $_POST['some6'];
        $some7 = $_POST['some7'];
        $some8 = $_POST['some8'];
```

Is that the right way or should i add mysql_real_escape_string(); to all of the variables?

Comment: Depends on what `escape_all` is.

Comment: Tell your "hired" about `mysqli`

Comment: You're really better off *not* screwing around with $_POST and instead  using techniques for writing SQL where escaping is not an issue (e.g. Named Parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like he's written a custom function to escape. As long as that escape_all function is calling mysql_real_escape string, it will technically work, although I wouldn't say it's the preferred solution for a few reasons.

Firstly, you'll want to be careful that you aren't escaping anywhere else, as it can easily lead to double escaping, which can cause other problems.

Also, you can end up escaping a whole lot of data that doesn't need to be escaped depending on the situation, if performance is a concern.

And yes, using mysqli instead of mysql is generally preferable.

Comment: Thanks.  I also checked the entire code and couldn't find the function escape_all.  So not sure what the hell he was doing.  I guess i can manually add it to the variables.

Comment: You're welcome! The function has to be there somewhere if the code isn't giving you some kind of error or notice. At any rate, manually escaping only what input needs to be escaped is a more ideal solution than a general escaping of the entire POST superglobal.